# For an SPA-website, which permalink-format would be better for SEO?

Tags: seo, blog, permalinks, single-page-application

I've created a SPA-website which will serve as my personal blog. I just can't quite decide on a permalink-structure for the blog-posts.

Which of the following three permalink-formats would work better for SEO?

My choices are:

**title** http://example.com/blog/post-title

**category/title** http://example.com/blog/tech-stuff/post-title

**year/month/title**
http://example.com/blog/2015/10/post-title

Comment: When you introduce permanent links, it is no longer single page.

Comment: My Ember-application just rewrites the URL and there is also a static version of it for the crawlers.

Comment: See [What is good URI design?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2105/what-is-good-uri-design) What are you trying to get indexed (e.g., blogs on your site by date, or a category like "tech-stuff"...)?

Answer (score 1):

Ideal URLs should be:

- Unique
- Descriptive
- Easy to remember
- Easy to type

I would:

- Leave out extra directories such as "tech-stuff" or dates
- Use the post title to be descriptive, but pare it down if possible when it gets long so that it is easier to type